# Why isn't $\text{Out}(S_6) \cong \{ e \}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I am learning about automorphisms, and came across the fact that:

$$\text{Out} (S_n) = \{e \}  \hspace{15pt} \text{when} \hspace{5pt} n \neq 6$$

I see why this is true for n in general, since $\text{Aut} (S_n) \cong S_n$ and I can convince myself that $\text{Inn}(S_n) \cong S_n$, meaning that:

$$\text{Out} (S_n) \cong \text{Aut}(S_n) / \text{Inn}(S_n) \cong \{e \}$$

What fails when n = 6?

Comment: For the reason see for example [here](http://settheory.net/Out(S6)). For $n=6$ there exists an effective action of $S_n$ on a set of $n$ elements, other than the natural one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outer Automorphisms of $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197686/outer-automorphisms-of-s-n).

Comment: $\psi$:$(12)\mapsto(15)(23)(46)$, $(13)\mapsto(14)(26)(35)$, $(14)\mapsto(13)(24)(56)$, $(15)\mapsto(12)(36)(45)$, $(16)\mapsto(16)(25)(34)$, $\psi\in \operatorname{Aut}(S_6)\setminus \operatorname{Inn}(S_6)$.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412670) for further reading.

Comment: For the sake of completeness [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134673/11619) we explain why an automorphism mapping transpositions to transpositions is automatically inner. As Derek Holt said, it is not difficult at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For all $n \ne 6$, single transpositions have larger centralizers in $S_n$ than elements of order $2$ in any other conjugacy classes. So any automorphism of $S_n$ must map transpositions to transpositions, and from that it is not too difficult to deduce that the automorphism must be inner.

But in $S_6$, the elements $(1,2)$ and $(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)$ both have centralizers of order $48$, and it turns out that there is an automorphism of $S_6$ that maps one to the other.